# What percent of VLQ flags are automated?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, low-quality-posts

I just ran in to a lot of code only answers in the Low Quality Posts review. I'm aware that some of these end up in review queue due to an automated process, but I'm wondering if there is any data available as to how many are manually flagged vs. auto-magically <strike>flagged</strike> dumped into the queue.

Just trying to figure out if its a user problem, or if the algorithm was just extra busy lately.

Comment: Technically, none of the flags are. You're seeing reviews for both human-flagged posts (both "very low quality" and "not an answer") mixed in with those that fall below the system quality thresholds. The latter don't have flags on them in the normal sense.

Comment: @BradLarson What's in a name? that which we call a flag
By any other name would smell as bad;

Comment: @BradLarson Alright... Is there any data on the ratio of real flags vs. "those that fall below the system quality thresholds"

Comment: I might be able to give you decent stats on that when the flag level gets back up there, but *someone* cleared out all the "very low quality" flags yesterday. Right now, I think 9 of the 13 review cases are due to user flags, but that's probably not a normal sampling.

Comment: @BradLarson it looks like there's a more than 100 posts in the in the queue at the moment, would it be possible to get a better sample? Is there any way for a normal user to access this data?

Comment: With 97 posts in the Low Quality Posts review queue, I'm seeing 40 "not an answer" and 29 "very low quality" flags total. 69 flagged posts out of 97 in review isn't too far off from 9 out of 13 last night.

Comment: @BradLarson So, would you guess that most of the "code only answer" type reviews are coming from the system algorithm or users, or is the data not that conclusive?

Comment: @BradLarson perhaps a better question... Is there a user query or stats page where one could find a break down of this info?

Comment: I see only three of these in all the user-cast flags, so I'm guessing those are primarily coming from the system heuristics. I know I've seen a lot of disputed reviews on those, and the reviews were rarely triggered by flags. Don't have hard numbers, though.

Comment: @BradLarson So it sounds like the posts ending up in review is a system problem and then it becomes a user problem from there.